# MapDB | reading in batches

Tags: kotlin, mapdb

How do I read records from MapDB in batches, instead of reading all at once ?

I have a list of say 1,000 records that I have persisted on disk through MapDB.

```
private fun storeRecordsInFile(records : List<Record>): String {
    val fileName = "/some/location/temp_file.db"
    val db = DBMaker.fileDB(fileName).fileMmapEnable().closeOnJvmShutdown().make()
    val diskBasedRecordsList = db.indexTreeList("recordsList").create()
    records.forEach { diskBasedRecordsList.add(it) }

    db.commit()
    db.close()

    return fileName
}
```

I am able to read all of these records at once.

```
private fun readRecordsFromFile(fileName: String): List<Record> {
    val db = DBMaker.fileDB(fileName).fileMmapEnable().make()
    val diskBasedRecordsList = db.indexTreeList("recordsList").open()

    //read from disk based list
    val recordsList = mutableListOf<Record>()
    val size = diskBasedRecordsList.size
    for(i in 0 until size-1){
        recordsList.add(diskBasedRecordsList[i] as Record)
    }

    db.close()
    return recordsList
}
```

However, I would want to read them in a chunk/batch of only 100 at a time in memory (i.e. without fetching the entire 1000 records in memory at once) ?